# Will Internet Explorer run on Windows 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10

Will Internet Explorer run on Windows 10?

I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere.

I have just updated to Windows 10 and need to be able to do web development testing on Internet Explorer, but when I go to http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/internet-explorer/download-ie
it says "Looking for Internet Explorer? You’re in the right place, but Internet Explorer requires a Windows PC."

Comment: If only IE11 is in Windows 10, but you need IE10 I think you can get a VM for testing on http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/.

Comment: I have to admit though, saying "Internet Explorer requires a Windows PC" when you're browsing with Edge, has got to be among the stupidest mistaken diagnostic messages I've ever seen.

Comment: I think the better way is to use VM as Jamil suggested, as it provides multiple versions of IE even including IE6

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 is *included* with Windows 10. It is not, however, the default browser; Edge is the default. To run it, you should search for Internet Explorer: click the Start Button, then start typing "Internet". It should show up as a search result.

Once you have found it, I recommend you pin it to the Taskbar, or the Start Menu, so you can find it again quickly.

Comment: Doh!!! I didn't even think to search for it in Win10 what a plonker I am. haha. Thanks for your speedy reply :)

Comment: It doesn't help that they made the application icon for Edge look so much like the one for IE. :)

Comment: And here I was thinking there would come a day where we won't have to bother making websites compatible with IE. Sigh.

Comment: @RossPresser If they didn't, Grandma would be wondering why the Internet disappeared.

Comment: IE is left over for enterprise users. Enterprise application vendors somehow get a pass on requiring outdated technologies to make their software work.

Comment: You can [enable Edge engine in IE](http://superuser.com/q/944785/101850) and live with the latest technologies without changing your workflow.

Comment: I search for internet and internet explorer doesn't show up.

Answer (score 25):

I would strongly recommend using a Virtual Machine from Microsoft's [modern.ie](https://www.modern.ie/) site.

They have Windows virtual machines with a range of different IE versions and Windows versions. They are awesome.

Comment: Quote: "..and need to be able to do web development testing on Internet Explorer.."

Comment: That's exactly what modern.ie IS testing ie in a stable environment...

Comment: Note, however, that according to the license terms, modern.ie VMs are not licensed for "commercial use" - so if you do web development for money, you are probably not allowed to use them.

Comment: @sleske, IANAL, but I'm fairly sure that's not what Microsoft meant.  The sentence before that is "You may use the software for testing purposes only."  By "no commercial use" they're trying to prohibit things like a service that takes screenshots of websites on various IE versions.

Comment: @cjm: Well, that's what our licensing experts said (see my answer to [Modern.IE VM license](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/244472/modern-ie-vm-license/283197)). They might be wrong, of course...

Comment: It would make absolutely no (business)sense that Microsoft would provide the vms for hobbyist use only. It is very likely that your licensing experts are being over-cautious as lawyers usually are.

Comment: Microsoft have always insisted that you need another license (or MSDN) in order to use a VM in a commercial environment. I don't see why they'd suddenly change that just for IE.

Comment: Because supporting ie is in their best interest. Ie gets a bashing from web devs and as a result they often don't get full support

Comment: do i need to DL VM software to run the VM or is it encapsulated in the zip??

Comment: You need to download vm software, Virtual box is free and works well

Answer (score 5):

Although **Microsoft Edge** is the **default** browser,
Internet Explorer 11 ***has been included*** in Windows 10 for ***legacy purposes***.
 Microsoft *recommends* developers to use Edge for new projects.

You can use Edge for website development, but there are *some* important plug-ins missing in Edge.

However, you can find it in **Start menu** -> ***All Apps*** -> (scroll all the way down to) ***Windows Accecessories*** -> *Internet Explorer*

OR

You can simply **type** in Internet explorer in the **start** menu, and you'll find it there.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer 11 can be changed to be default

1. Head over to the Settings app.
   You've got a few options here. The easiest is to head to the Action center and selecting "All settings". If you're on a device with a touch screen, swipe in from the right. If you're using a mouse and keyboard, click the Action center icon on the bottom right corner of the taskbar, or press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to get there.
2. Head to System, and then default apps.
   System is the option on the top left. Click (or tap) it, and you'll see a few more settings. The default apps section is down near the bottom of the column on the left.
3. Scroll down to Web browser, and make your choice.
   Web browser is down at the bottom of the list. Click it, and you'll be able to choose from all of the browsers you've got installed.

And that's it. If you want to change the rest of your default apps, you can do that here too. You can also choose the default apps for particular file types, or particular protocols -- if you'd like to use a particular app for any email address or map links you click, for example

Answer (score 2):

If Windows 10 isn't installed under All Apps > Windows Accessories, you can install it through Programs & Features > Turn Windows features on or off:

[image]

After a reboot Internet Explorer appears under All Apps > Windows Accessories or can be searched in the start menu.

Comment: In most (maybe all) versions of Windows, selecting "Internet Explorer" in the list of Windows features doesn't install it.  It is already installed, and that checkbox only controls desktop icon and start menu entry. (And quicklaunch, which no longer exists)

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm running Windows 10 Pro, perhaps it's slightly different there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to find Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 10:

Click the Windows button (Start menu). Then click All Apps. Scroll down to Windows Accessories. There you'll find Internet Explorer.

Comment: no need to scroll through a lot of menus. a simple search will do

Answer (score 0):

You can find Internet Explorer 11 by searching for it.

Tap on the Search icon in the taskbar. Type "internet" - you can find it as Internet explorer. Open it then pin it to the taskbar.

Internet Explorer 11 is embedded in Windows 10 but not the default anymore. Edge is the default browser. You can change it to Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: This is a duplication of information in previous answers.