# Windows 10, Add remove programs does not re-enable Internet explorer 11

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I am running a windows 10 OS and trying to operate QuickBooks which requires that you must have Internet explorer on your pc to use.

[image: QuickBooks installation completion message]

I need this QuickBooks program for my school, and I have tried everything I can think of. When I search for Internet Explorer on the search bar nothing comes up.

[image: Search results for Internet Explorer on Start]

I really have tried everything. The main problem seems to be in the Windows add remove featured programs dialog box. When I click internet explorer to be enabled, it goes through the normal, "setting up your system" when completed, it says to restart. I restart, come back and the box is unchecked. Internet explorer does not exits.

I need QuickBooks to work on this laptop. I desperately need it for school. Is there no where to hard install or force my pc to enable internet explorer? I have edge, and can't revert to internet explorer because the option just isn't there for me. I hope someone can help.

Please note: I have contacted my college IT department, they have failed to make internet explorer active/enabled on my pc. We ran updates, as well as a registry check to no avail. I have also sent an email to QuickBooks asking them what to do. I am just falling behind on school work and am paranoid. I do appreciate your help.

- Dilara

Comment: This a personal PC?  What version of Quickbooks?  Did you or anyone in control of your PC uninstall IE11 because it isn't normally disabled

Comment: [IE11 is enabled or disabled in Windows Features](http://superuser.com/questions/948764/will-internet-explorer-run-on-windows-10)

Comment: Set IE as your default web browser...http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-set-your-default-browser-windows-10-just-5-steps

Comment: Personal computer, I disabled it originally Ramhound. 
I cannot set it as anything because it doesn't exist in my system. 

I need to have it installed/active on my PC before I can use it or make it default. 

It seems like the best choice is to try to find a way to manually install IE 11 or something.

Moab, thanks but like I said, IE11 does not exist in my pc. It doesn't let me add it and keep it on my computer.

Comment: I take these steps: Control Panel> Programs and futures> Turn Windows features on or off> (at this point I see that IE is not checked, I click to make sure it's turned on)> it goes through it's regular we are installing process and prompts for restarting PC for it to take affect.

I restart the computer and go back into Windows programs... The box is unchecked and IE doesn't show up in my search bar as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after trying many different methods like fixing registry and trying all the suggested Microsoft solutions... I had no choice but to reset my laptop. That did resolve the issue.

I just did the simple, keep my files reset. IE now is turned on in the Add remove windows programs options and QuickBooks work just fine.

Thanks for all the previous input anyway though I appreciate it.

To reset your PC without loosing your files:

- Go to setting in windows start.
- Go to Update and Security
- Then to Recovery
- Reset this PC > Click on Get started
- [Here you can completely reset your PC or do a partial reset where you can   keep your files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6bol.png)
- IE will now be able to stay on if you couldn't turn it back on again because you turned it off like I had for what ever reason.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading a Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 10 Home. Internet Explorer was not visible in searches, and the directory for the application contained only residual files.

I tried reinstalling via the IE 11 offline installer, but the installer told me that IE was already installed in a later version.

Under "Add programs and features", Internet Explorer 11 was unticked. If i ticked the box, and pressed OK, nothing happened, except the dialog closed.

My solution was the following:

- Go into program and features under Add/Remove applications
- There I saw Internet Explorer unticked as described.
- Tick the box, AND UNTICK IT AGAIN!
- Press Okay in the bottom, and answer YES when Windows asks if you want to remove Internet Explorer 11.
- Reopen Add programs and features, and TICK the box. Press OK to leave the dialog.
- Windows will now ask if you want to install Internet Explorer 11, press YES.
- Reboot the computer

This restored my Internet Explorer, both when searching and in the taskbar. The version is also the latest, without any issues (that I have encountered).

Comment: It worked! You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in Powershell

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 –Online
```

If that doesn't work. then get a Win10 CD or download the ISO and type this

```
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:E:\sources\sxs\microsoft-windows-internetexplorer-optional-package.cab
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, extracted win 10 ISO, then into "sxs" and extracted the IE package as named below. just replace after packagepath with the path of your file location and enter.

```
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:D:\Win10_20H2_English_x64\sources\sxs\Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Optional-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~
```