# Edge engine on Windows Server 2016

Tags: internet-explorer-11

As you may know already, Windows Server 2016 RTM does not feature Edge browser, only Internet Explorer, like in Windows 10 Enterprise ltsb. The engine of Edge, edgehtml.dll, is present, but I could not find a way to enable the use of it in Internet Explorer 11. I prefer the Edge engine for performance and security reasons.

Tried the solutions I found on this website regarding Win 10 Ent ltsb:  [How to enable Edge mode in IE?](https://superuser.com/questions/944785/how-to-enable-edge-mode-in-ie), but none of them worked:

- Could not find registry entries required.
- Also mshtml.dll , the engine of Internet Explorer, it is not present in Program Files/Internet Explorer, only in System32.
- I have tried the symlink solution suggested on this site, I could not use it, System32 in Windows Server 2016 is locked from modification, even taking ownership of the files did not seemed to work.

Any of you have at least an idea of how the use of edgehtml.dll can be enabled in Internet Explorer 11 instead of mshtml.dll ?

Comment: "Tried the solutions I found on this website" - please post link to them you found and didn't work (also include what was the issue exaclty). Also please format your question to make it readable (use different paragraphs for different topics)

Comment: Posted the link, tried to split the paragraphs, I could not do that. I am new to this site, anyway. I guess it is one topic, noneoftheless.

Comment: You cannot enable edge mode in IE that feature was removed over a year ago.  QED.  Unless you can install Edge (have not researched it) what you want won't be possible

Comment: If you checked the link from the post, you will shall see that as late as december, some members from here managed to enable it using symlinks. But that was the November Update (on Windows Server 2016 November Update was in Technical Preview 4) and it was Windows 10, less then a year from now. Up to Technical Preview 5, released in May 2016, Edge was fully available, but it was removed in RTM, that is, more or less, the equivalent of the Anniversary Update in Windows 10. So, the question remains open. Some people managed to copy Edge from Windows 10 to WS 2016 RTM, but that is illegal.

Comment: Posted this on the topic I gave link above as well:I have managed to create the symlink on Windows Server 2016. But the browsing engine test pages showed Internet Explorer 11. Discovered that edgehtml.dll is a phantom dll, it is actually mshtml.dll renamed, I so this at version number, it was 11, instead of 14. This is why webpages so it as IE.  You can try, to check to version of the file edgehtml.dll in Windows 10 Enterprise ltsb, on the Details tab, if it is so.

Comment: @Vyzantion in case you are still using it... [Edge works in Server 2016 now](https://superuser.com/a/1482736/505087)

Comment: I use Windows Server 2019 now. If you mean the Chromium based Edge, I know and I am not interested into any Chromium based things. Anyway, thank you.