# How to install Microsoft Edge on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016

In the IE browser, I can search and find the following site on MS:

[image]

But when I click on 'Try Now', I am greeted by this prompt:

[image]

And then this message:

[image]

I have also checked 'Add and remove program' but I am not able to locate Edge.

Is there a simple way I can install Edge to Window Server 2016?

Comment: Are you using a LTSB (1607) version of Windows Server 2016 by chance?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/66f8e3b1-0916-4849-8d86-5cccc6845b89/how-to-install-edge-on-2016-server?forum=ws2016

Comment: Actually I am not sure. I am running the server on AWS EC2. The AMI is ami-c1a6bda2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like MS recognized the folly in this and changed their minds, this works for Server 2016 now.

The official version can be downloaded at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge

[image: screen shot of edge download options with circle]

Comment: This is a beta version. Is there a download link for the regular, stable version which can be installed on Windows Server as well?

Comment: @FlorianWinter updated for the non-beta version which is now available too

Comment: After I wrote my comment, I discovered "Edge for Business", which is basically Edge, except you can download it: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business.
On the link you posted, I have desperately looked for a download link for Windows and couldn't find one.

Comment: @FlorianWinter I added a screenshot of where the download options are on the page. As shown above, the Windows download is the first one on the left where it says "Get Microsoft Edge", this is not normal (non-business) version.

Comment: The Windows link is not a download link, but a `microsoft-edge:` link, which does not work on Windows Server (at least I could not get it to work). See also https://superuser.com/a/1322286/333024

Comment: @FlorianWinter I see that the "Start Microsoft Edge" _button_ is a `microsoft-edge:` link. But I said to use the "Get Microsoft Edge" link (blue text not a button) just above it, that's the one for download. Not sure why MS made it so obscure...

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft Edge was removed from Windows Server 2016 during the release candidate stage. It cannot be installed on it either.

According to Microsoft:

> The Long-Term Servicing Branch (LTSB) versions of Windows, including Windows Server 2016, don't include Microsoft Edge or many other Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps. These apps and their services are frequently updated with new functionality, and can't be supported on systems running the LTSB operating systems. For customers who require the LTSB for specialized devices, we recommend using Internet Explorer 11.
>
> — ["Microsoft Edge requirements and language support"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/hardware-and-software-requirements). *Microsoft Edge - Deployment Guide for IT Pros*. Microsoft Corporation (27 July 2017) via Microsoft Docs.

The "Try Now" link on the web page you've found simply tries to invoke a hyperlink whose protocol is `microsoft-edge:`. Internet Explorer recognizes this protocol as belonging to a UWP and tries to invoke that app, but only after asking you. What you see in screenshot #3 is the result of that app (Microsoft Edge) not being installed.

Comment: Answer is now wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Make sure you click the image description.

Make sure server is install mode if using RDS server (change user /install)

You can install Edge, I was able to go the microsoft site: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download

Scroll down until you see select channel and version, choose Stable 86 (Current and supported)

Then click> Select Build 86.0.622.63

Then click> Select Platform > choose the Windows 64-bit
Click download.

You should get the normal install prompts to download and install, depending on what type of browser you are using.

Comment: On a fresh install of Windows Server 2019, that page didn't work for me in the installed IE - you couldn't select anything for channel, version etc