# Kiosk Browser in Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 2016 (v.1607)

Tags: browser, kiosk, windows-iot-core

I bought an all-in-one monitor with Windows IOT, I want to build a browser kiosk locked in one page.
Is it possibile with this version of Windows?
I did not find Edge and moreover I did not find any kiosk options mentioned here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-methods

I can change browser, but seems that chrome or firefox don't have kiosk mode and their kiosk plugin are deprecated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Microsoft Edge on Windows Server 2016?](https://superuser.com/questions/1247448/how-to-install-microsoft-edge-on-windows-server-2016)

Comment: Why Edge should be the only solution for a Kiosk Browser? The question is really different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome *does* have a Kiosk mode, and you can read how to [set it up here](https://www.integraxor.com/launch-web-browsers-kiosk-mode/) without any extension, along with other browser's kiosk configurations.

- Make a new shortcut with a right-click on chrome.exe
- Choose **Properties** after right-clicking on the new shortcut.
- On the “Shortcut” tab, go into the Target field, go to the end of that
  field,  and add `--kiosk` then the URL you want the Kiosk link to go
  to.

For more about Chrome Kiosk mode, visit [Google's Chrome Help Pages](https://support.google.com/chrome/search?q=set%20up%20kiosk%20mode%20).